# Prolog - Make an app that does nothing and runs forever

Tags: loops, prolog, infinite

Any good ways to do this?

Comment: You're looking for good ways to do something bad ?  It's a bit like asking for a good way to eat a dolphin.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but:

```
foo :- foo.
```

But "forever" is a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

So a loop with nothing but repeat and fail inside it should do then?

Comment: loopx :-
repeat,
fail.

that is.